# How to develop client side library and npm library ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I would like to develop a JS test library for client & node.
I need to develop for two different repo's?
Lets take for example **QUnit**:
for client side I will use:

> https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.3.0.js

But for node develop, I will use :

> npm install qunitjs

Those are 2 different code repo's, aren't?

For the example, lets puts aside the testrunner, etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally the "npm" used to stand for the "Node Package Manager".

Currently, the npm Registry is a public collection of packages of open-source code for Node.js, front-end web apps, mobile apps, robots, routers, and countless other needs of the JavaScript community.

And `npm` is the command line client that allows developers to install and publish those packages.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/about

So you can use npm to package front-end code just like you can use npm to package Node code. Sometimes it makes sense to publish two packages - one for frontend and one for backend - but sometimes you can have just one.

For packaging frontend code there are more options like Bower: https://bower.io/

For packaging Node code the most popular choice is npm but you can install code directly from GitHub or other git repos.

As an example you can see my module `tco` that is on npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tco

But also on GitHub:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-tco

So you could install it with npm either from the npm Registry or from GitHub:

```
npm install tco           # <-- from npm registry
npm install rsp/node-tco  # <-- from github
```

Additionaly you can use it on the frontend from the CDN available for all code on GitHub:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rsp/node-tco/v0.0.12/tco.min.js"></script>
```

If you want your code available on that CDN as well, see RawGit:

- https://rawgit.com/

Comment: thanks, there isn't any diffrence between the code in rhe CDN or the code from the NPM?

Comment: @ShayZambrovski In this case there isn't but there would be if I published on npm something else than I pushed to GitHub. This CDN is exactly what is on GitHub, or what was there when it was cached. See https://rawgit.com/ everything is explained there.